# How to switch contenttemplate dependent which view model object?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

How to settings which view showup when specific viewmodel set?  i read this explain with data template but i still dont understand. cause it dont show all code that use data template as switch view. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2009/february/patterns-wpf-apps-with-the-model-view-viewmodel-design-pattern

```
<Window x:Class="Pandora.Views.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:Pandora.ViewModels"
        Title="Pandora" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.ContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:IndexViewModel}">
                <TextBlock>Index Content</TextBlock>
            </DataTemplate>

            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:DashboardViewModel}">
                <TextBlock>Dashboard Content</TextBlock>
            </DataTemplate>
    </Window.ContentTemplate>
</Window>
```

C#

```
using Pandora.ViewModels;

namespace Pandora.Views;

public partial class MainWindow
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
      DataContext = new IndexViewModel();
    }
}
```

Comment: When you create a `DataTemplate` and give it an `x:Type` but you do not give it a key, you are saying that it should be the default `DataTemplate` used whenever the `Content` property is set to that type.  However you should put these default `DataTemplates` in the `Window.Resources` section, not in the `Window.ContentTemplate` property.  Will that even build?.

Comment: i put insinde contenttemplate it build but the content cant switch. if i put into window resources. just white blank.

Comment: First step is to move the DataTemplates to the Window.Resources property.

Comment: You don't need to switch `DataTemplates`.  WPF does it for you.  That's the point of having default `DataTemplate`s.  Just set the current value of the `Content` property to whatever ViewModel object you want.  If you have defined a default `DataTemplate` for that View-model's type and you've put it in the `Resources` section, then WPF will switch to its specific UI automatically.   Better yet, bind the `Content` property to some property somewhere.  So you can just set it in another view-model

Answer (score 0):

For Window to show anything it should have some `Content` (empty Window template contains `<Grid></Grid>` element). Simply copy Content from DataContext by using binding.

In your case you want to show elements, which don't have visual representation of their own (IndexViewModel, DashboardViewModel), so they require a custom DataTemplate. You already have, just put them in Resources.

```
<Window x:Class="Pandora.Views.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:Pandora.ViewModels"
        Title="Pandora" 
        Content="{Binding}"
        Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:IndexViewModel}">
            <TextBlock>Index Content</TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:DashboardViewModel}">
            <TextBlock>Dashboard Content</TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
</Window>
```

or more common method which uses a separate element to insert custom content:

```
<Window x:Class="Pandora.Views.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:Pandora.ViewModels"
        Title="Pandora" 
        Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:IndexViewModel}">
            <TextBlock>Index Content</TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:DashboardViewModel}">
            <TextBlock>Dashboard Content</TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
         <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}"/>
         <TextBlock Text="Demo watermark" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" IsHitTestVisible="False"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must assign the `IndexViewModel` or `DashboardViewModel` instance to the `Window.Content` property. The `ContentTemplate` applies to the data object that is the current value of the `Content` property:

```cs
public partial class MainWindow
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
      this.Content = new IndexViewModel();
    }
}
```